# How to get error message for mail already in use?

Tags: php, email

How to do it so people can not register with the same email address several times. So they instead get an error. like "sorry this email is already in use"

Here is my code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

  if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])&& !empty($_POST['mail'])) {
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $mail=$_POST['mail'];

    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','123') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('ProjectC') or die("cannot select DB");


    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$user."'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows==0)
    {
      $sql="INSERT INTO login(username,password,mail) VALUES('$user','$pass','$mail')";

      $result=mysql_query($sql);


      if($result){
        echo "Account Successfully Created";
      } else {
        echo "Failure!";
      }

    } else {
      echo "That username already exists! Please try again with another.";
    }

  } else {
    echo "All fields are required!";
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? Wrong results?

Comment: How does that code not do that?

Comment: Pepole can register twice with the same email. but i dont want that. so they instead get an error message. example "sorry but the email is already in use"

Comment: mysql_ functions are deprecated, please use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/tr/book.pdo.php) instead of mysql_ functions.

Comment: You have SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code - don't put it live!

Comment: I know it, im new in PHP and i am just learning.

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

1. Don't use `SELECT *` when you can enumerate column names.
2. Fetch your result sets. MySQL doesn't take well to unfetched result sets.
3. Instead of doing `SELECT something FROM table WHERE condition` do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE condition`, fetch the one-row result set, and look at the count.
4. Consider putting a unique constraint on your `mail` column. Then an insert with a duplicate in that column will fail.
5. Don't use the `mysql_` API, instead use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.  `mysql_` has been deprecated because it's grossly insecure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a UNIQUE constraint on your database table, so that the query will fail.

```
ALTER TABLE login ADD CONSTRAINT unique_email UNIQUE (mail)
```

Running this query once (or otherwise setting a unique constraint from a database manager tool like phpMyAdmin) will make the insert query fail and generate an error.